# OptionRequestDenied error when uploading/downloading file in S3 hosted in china

Tags: amazon-s3

I am facing weird error wherein when I am uploading/downloading **ANY** file on S3 bucket hosted in CHINA, I am getting OptionRequestDenied error. Something to note here is that I am facing this issue **ONLY** when I am using Jio fibre internet connection. However when I use any other ISP, including JIO mobile hotspot I don't encounter this issue.
Also would like to inform that using JIO Fibre Internet I am ABLE TO perform ANY action on S3 bucket which are hosted outside CHINA.

Looks to me some firewall issue but not sure how to go about with this.

Would love to hear back if anyone has any suggestion to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by configuring 1.1.1.1 (cloudfare) dns server in my router to resolve this.